# Обработка Multipart Request с пустым полем на backend java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, angular2, java-ee

Есть контроллер и эндпойнт обрабатывающие POST-запрос, в котором приходит XML-файл и др. параметры:

```
@RestController
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/label-integrity")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LabelIntegrityController {

    private final IntegrityLabelService integrityLabelService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/verify-double", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    @Secured("ROLE_rPageMain")
    public LabelResultTypeDto getVerifyDoubleLabelIntegrity(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, SuvLogFilterDto suvLogFilterDto) {
        return this.integrityLabelService.verifyDoubleLabelIntegrity(suvLogFilterDto, file);
    }
}
```

С фронта запрос отправляется следующим образом:

```
public getVerifyDoubleLabelIntegrity(id: string, messageGuid: string, eventCode: Array<string>, typeMessage: string, destination: string, file?: FormData) {
    const url = `${this._url}/verify-double`;

    return this.http
      .post<VerifyLabelIntegrityResponseModel>(url, file, { params: { id, messageGuid, eventCode, typeMessage, destination } })
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => this.logger.debug(`post VerifyDoubleLabelIntegrity`)),
        take(1),
        share()
      );
  }
```

Объект **"file"** может быть заполнен - XML-файл, а может быть **undefined**.

Когда объект **"file"** заполнен, то всё нормально, но когда он не заполнен (данный кейс необходим), то возникает ошибка:

> org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content
> type '' not supported

Пробовал создавать пустой объект и отправлять его на бэк:

```
if (file === null || file === undefined) {
      file = new FormData();
    }
```

Но это вызывает другую ошибку:

> org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException:
> Required request part 'file' is not present

Пробовал в описание эндпойнта добавить MediaType.ALL_VALUE:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/verify-double", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, MediaType.ALL_VALUE})
```

Но это тоже вызвало уже другую ошибку.

Пробовал в аннотации параметра прописать `requared = false`, но это вызвало ту же ошибку:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/verify-double", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    @Secured("ROLE_rPageMain")
    public LabelResultTypeDto getVerifyDoubleLabelIntegrity(@RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file, SuvLogFilterDto suvLogFilterDto) {
        ...
    }
```

> org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content
> type '' not supported at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:227)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:422)

Оф. доках нашёл пример различных вариантов использования и даже unit-тестирования Multipart Request [Multipart Request Handling in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/sprint-boot-multipart-requests), но варианта с пустым form-data нет.

Как можно прописать контроллер, что бы он мог обрабатывать запросы с пустым объектом `@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file`?

Как вариант решения:

- на фронте создать пустую форму:

  if (file === null || file === undefined) {
  file = new FormData();
  }
- на бэке `@RequestPart` в место `@RequestParam` && `required = false`

  @PostMapping(value = "/verify-double", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
  @Secured("ROLE_rPageMain")
  public LabelResultTypeDto getVerifyDoubleLabelIntegrity(@RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file,  SuvLogFilterDto suvLogFilterDto) {
  ...
  }

Comment: Ну как вариант, попробуй отправлять не просто пустую FormData, а еще назначить ей правильный Content-Type. вдруг поможет....? )

Comment: @NikolayGabaraev, что-то я у объекта FormData не нашел, как ему можно задать Content-Type, можно пример?

Comment: Не, ты когда отправляешь запрос на сервер, с пустой FormData - подкрути Headers вручную.

Comment: Кстати, а если через try-catch это обработать?

Comment: Так. Стоп. а если просто в `@RequestParam` указать `defaultValue = null` и внутри контроллера это проверить?

Comment: @NikolayGabaraev, ```return this.http
      .post<VerifyLabelIntegrityResponseModel>(url, file, { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}), params: { id, messageGuid, eventCode, typeMessage, destination } })``` не помогло, тогда: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
 at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletR...

Comment: @NikolayGabaraev, try-catch не поможет - запрос ведь не проходит, не попадает в метод эндпойнта

Comment: @NikolayGabaraev, ```@RequestParam(defaultValue = null) MultipartFile file``` не даёт установить - значение должно быть константой

Comment: `@RequestParam(required = false)`  а так?

Comment: @NikolayGabaraev, ```@RequestParam(required = false)``` - та же ошибка